# View filter on multiple AND/OR combinations

Tags: filter, view

I'm trying to set up a view to filter on column Status (options are "WIP - Drafting", "Eng Check" and "Peer Check") and the name in columns "Drafter", "Eng" or "Peer".

Any one of the engineers could be the drafter, engineering checker, or peer checker.  I need to apply a filter "WIP - Drafting" and "Drafter" = username OR "Eng Check" and "Eng" = username OR "Peer Check" and "Peer" = username.

I've tried adding a calculated field to combine Status and Eng, Drafter, or Peer, but I can only select Status.  I cannot use the other columns because they select from the user pool instead of typing in plain text.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

*EDIT*  Not sure how to bump this or if the question isn't clear.  Anybody?

Comment: Maybe add an additional column that is filled by a workflow that copies the checker user info as plain text - at least then you can filter on usernames.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use SharePoint Designer? Not sure if this works with your needs, but might give you some ideas.

I'd add another field to the list, 'Current Engineer', and hide it from the forms so it doesn't confuse anyone.

Then I'd create a workflow that runs on modify, that checks the value of the status field and copies the correct engineer column to the 'Current Engineer' column.

Then, your view could use that field however you need, like 'Current Engineer' = [Me]  or using a hardcoded name.

Another way, if you don't have too many engineers. Create a wiki page for each engineer, and add multiple list views, one for each status. The filter for the first part could then be `"Status = WIP-Draft.." and Drafter = "Eddie".` The next web part would filter on `status 'Eng' and Engineer = "Eddie"`.... and so on.

That way they'd have a whole page and would see each status in a separate section of the page. It's a pain to set up initially but once you have it done it's very effective. I use this with my designers and they love having everything on one page without having to look at multiple views.

Comment: I don't have access to SharePoint Designer.  I've added a field for Current Engineer, but I'm not sure how to set up the flow to set the value.  I need some Get steps (I think), but I'm not sure how this would go together.

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with Flow. But you'd need it to do something like 'if status = WIP-Drafter , set current engineer to the value in drafter. and repeat that for all your status'. If you don't have too many engineers you could also make pages for each one - I'll expand on my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the question is quite unclear. To make sure I understand this correctly you want to have a filter available which is based on the user's job title?

Comment: There are three different roles a user can be: Drafter, Engineer, or Peer.  Eddie is a drafter for some drawings, but the engineer on other drawings and a peer on yet other drawings.  I need a filter to make a view for Eddie so he can see the drawings that:
1) Status = WIP - Drafting AND Drafter = Eddie
OR
2) Status = Eng Check AND Eng = Eddie
OR
3) Status = Peer Check AND Peer = Eddie